# Chrome not bringing in facebook app javascript onto page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, google-chrome

I have a facebook page below that works fine in Firefox, safari as well as the original iframed source in chrome.

However, the site does not load the javascript correctly in chrome on the actual app:

https://www.facebook.com/jobsatfarmers/app_635348913144151

Can someone please steer me in the right direction for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js instead http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js
replace all http:// with https://
console says:
[blocked] The page at https://bayardclient.com/farmerscareers/facebook/ ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your page is trying to load from HTTP while Facebook is on HTTPS, so there is a nonsecure to secure issue with Javascript at least. Try to change jQuery to load e.g. from Google (//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js for protocol relative and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js if you wish to include the protocol).

By the way, same issue is repeated with the font you are trying to load. You should also refer to it without protocol or with HTTPS included. Otherwise it will not display either.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies guys!  This did the trick.  Good to know.. Weird though since we have a SSL certificate on the bayard client source.

Comment: Just for the future sake: it is NOT your server or its certificate that raised the security error but the reference to non-secure sites (either same domain or third party). Using https://code.jquery.com/ would not also be a good option in my opinion as it seems to be self signed and will cause even more nasty looking errors for clients. In the future you can use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're either not loading jQuery successfully, or you're loading it successfully but the `$` alias for the `jQuery` object is not being set up properly:

[image]

Make sure you're loading jQuery before you get to this code, and that nothing is messing with the `$` alias.